# Database Create Operation Failed on Cloudant Local Dashboard

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Cloudant Data Layer Local Edition version :- 1.0.0.3
Linux Distribution and version :- CentOs 6.6 
I recently installed Cloudant data layer local edition 1.0.0.3 . Configured it properly (1 load balancer and 3 data node)and launched dashboard on browser.

Then I put  credentials for admin account and got entered in dashboard. Clicked on “Add New Database “, It asked for enter the name of database  and as soon as I entered name and pressed create button it showed error :**database does not exist.**

Also every time I refresh the page it showed different-different databases in UI.  I tried to get all databases from terminal as well with curl command . I have 3 data nodes in my cluster and I suppose to get same databases whether I fired curl command to any of my data node as they syn with each other but I got different–different output .

**Commands Snippet**

```
[root@******1983 repo]# curl -X GET -u admin:***** http://******2031:5984
["_users","first_testing_database","metrics_app","t1"]

[root@******1983 repo]# curl -X GET -u admin:***** http://*****2032:5984
["first_data","metrics","metrics_app","new","stats"]

[root@8****1983 repo]# curl -X GET -u admin:***** http://*****2033:5984
["metrics_app"]
```

Even though, I managed to create  a document in one of my created   database but when i tried to get same document from curl command it says(running subsequently 3 times) :-

1. Database does not exist
2. Missing
3. The Data

The data

After it fetched the data, if I ran the command again then it would repeat the above sequence in a pattern.

**Commands Snippet**

```
[root@*****1983 log]#curl -X GET http://*******/try/c3cd00e3211b9a4de4091da7c9000d5c
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
[root@*****1983 log]# curl -X GET http://*******/try/c3cd00e3211b9a4de4091da7c9000d5c
{"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}
[root@*****1983 log]# curl -X GET http://*******/try/c3cd00e3211b9a4de4091da7c9000d5c
{"_id":"c3cd00e3211b9a4de4091da7c9000d5c","_rev":"1-9bc8307931d018808037c1c58fc7d1ad","designation":"software eng.","stream":"analytics"}
[root@****1983 log]# curl -X GET http://********/try/c3cd00e3211b9a4de4091da7c9000d5c
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
[root@****1983 log]# curl -X GET http://********/try/c3cd00e3211b9a4de4091da7c9000d5c
{"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}
[root@*****1983 log]# curl -X GET http://*******/try/c3cd00e3211b9a4de4091da7c9000d5c
{"_id":"c3cd00e3211b9a4de4091da7c9000d5c","_rev":"1-9bc8307931d018808037c1c58fc7d1ad","designation":"software eng.","stream":"analytics"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your nodes don't know of each other. You probably missed this step during installation:
"Once the installation and configuration is completed on all nodes, re-run configure.sh on the first database node. This step joins all the nodes to create a cluster of the database nodes. It also creates the metrics database that is utilized by the Metrics application. "

Comment: i completed all the steps of installation including re-run configure.sh on the first database node after completion of installation and configuration on other nodes. i guess this was happening because of the wrong combination of node address entries in /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network .when i corrected them and re-configure all the nodes ,my previous error was gone but caught in a new one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603111/cloudant-internal-server-error