# Cloudant - Internal Server Error

Tags: cloudant

Cloudant local data edition version : 1.0.0.3

Linux distribution and version : centos 6.6

I recently installed Cloudant local data edition , configured it properly on 4 node cluster(1 load balancer and 3 data nodes).
everything looked fine then fired some curl command to create , retrieve and delete databases but got internal_server_error.
When i launched cloudant dashboard and got entered as admin , the specified operation actually was occuring but on terminal 
i got error messages.

**Command Snippet**

```
[root@******1983 etc]# curl -X GET -u admin:****  http://*******/_all_dbs
["_users","first_data","first_testing_database","metrics","metrics_app","new","stats","t1","t_alpha"]
[root@******1983 etc]# curl -X GET -u admin:****  http://********/t_alpha
{"error":"error","reason":"internal_server_error",}
[root@******1983 etc]# curl -X DELETE -u admin:**** http://********/t_alpha
{"error":"error","reason":"internal_server_error",}
```

i used the instructions to use the Weatherreport utility to check the health of my Cloudant cluster. i set the path using export command:
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/cloudant/bin
then run weatherreport but it says "could not connect to local cluster node".
i have given  full address of my all 4 nodes in /etc/hosts , /etc/sysconfig/network , /etc/resolve.conf

**command snippet**

```
[root@******** etc]# /opt/cloudant/bin/weatherreport
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [warning] Could not connect to the local cluster node 'cloudant@********#', some checks will not run.
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_tcp_queues: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_search: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_safe_to_rebuild: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_process_memory: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_process_calls: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_nodes_connected: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_node_stats: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_message_queues: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_memory_use: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_membership: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_mem3_sync: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_ioq: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_internal_replication: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_disk: nodedown
['cloudant_diag3989@******** #'] [crit] Bad rpc call executing check weatherreport_check_custodian: nodedown
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudant Local uses the FQDN to communicate between nodes. Please ensure you have the correct FQDN and corresponding IP address for all nodes in /etc/hosts on ALL nodes (load balancer and DB nodes).
i.e.
192.168.0.10  lb1.cloudant.local lb1
192.168.0.11  db1.cloudant.local db1
192.168.0.12  db2.cloudant.local db2
192.168.0.13  db3.cloudant.local db3

/etc/resolv.conf (not resolve.conf ^^) should (only) contain your DNS IP address(es) on all nodes.
i.e.
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 8.8.4.4

AFAIK, /etc/sysconfig/network only applies to Debian/Ubuntu and contains network info for the local machine only.

Comment: I set the FQDN and corresponding IP address for all nodes in /etc/hosts on all nodes.
but still when i tried to fire Weatherreport from one of my data node it says: could not connect to local cluster node.(see exact error in my post).
when i was installing cloudant ,user named "cloudant" was created automatically.When i fired Weatherreport utillity, Cloudant user tried to connect to same machine from which i fired that utility.
could you provide more info about cloudant user and this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check /opt/cloudant/etc/vm.args file. You have set incorrect -name parameter with machine name. This is clear from error message

```
"Could not connect to the local cluster node 'cloudant@********#'.
```

Here extra # is present at the end of machine name.